# Given a list of a, select 2 elements from the list, combine them and add them to new list. Repeat until new list is the same size as input list

Tags: haskell

I'm continuing to learn some Haskell, at the moment I would like to implement a very simple and contrived genetic algorithm (something which I have done in several other languages). I am struggling with some most basic stuff right now though in Haskell as I can't stop thinking imperatively.

So, as part of a genetic algorithm, you have a selection and crossover phase, where you select 2 members from the current population, cross them over to create a single member for a new population. You repeat this process until the size of the new population is equal to the size of the input population.

In Kotlin, C#, Java etc the solution would/could look something like this:

```
val newPopulation = emptyList()
while (newPopulation.size < inputPopulation.size) {
    val mum = selectFrom(inputPopulation)
    val dad = selectFrom(inputPopulation)
    val child = mum.crossover(dad)
    newPopulation.add(child)
}
return newPopulation
```

However, in Haskell you need to think less imperatively and more in terms of declarations of mappings. This is where I am beginning to struggle. For instance, there is no "simple" way of declaring a new list and then doing a while (newList.size < oldList.size) { // Do stuff }, so I am assuming I need to use a more functional approach to this (i.e. unfold/fold/zip etc). I just don't know what a solution would look like, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: as many have mention in the answers, the typical approach would be to use `zipWith crossover` The only thing that isn't clear is which selection schema you use when using `selectFrom` function. For example: can `selectFrom` repeat mum/dad in different iterations?

Comment: @ismor - yea the selected elements wouldn't be removed from the original list (I'm not too concerned about the end algorithm being perfect or optimal, I just find implementing GA's quite a nice "hello world" when learning a new language as it touches on multiple language constructs and you end up needing to do a bit of a deep dive on the language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you *can* do it imperatively in Haskell, it's just horrible (like it is in other languages). Would look something like

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad.Loops (whileM)

  do
    newPopulation <- newIORef []
    whileM_ (((<length inputPopulation).length<$>readIORef newPopulation) $ do
      mum <- selectFrom inputPopulation
      dad <- selectFrom inputPopulation
      let child = crossover mum dad
      modifyIORef (child:) newPopulation
    readIORef newPopulation
```

There's much awkward in here:

- The `while` loop is far too general. You know upfront how many iterations it will be, so no need to query the `newPopulation` length over and over for the stop condition!
- In each iteration you add exactly one element to the result. Well, of course there are dedicated control structures for that, no need to do it manually with dangerous mutable updates.

So,

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

  do
    replicateM (length inputPopulation) $ do
       mum <- selectFrom inputPopulation
       dad <- selectFrom inputPopulation
       let child = crossover mum dad
       return child
```

or shorter

```
    replicateM (length inputPopulation) $ crossover
       <$> selectFrom inputPopulation<*>selectFrom inputPopulation
```

Alternatively, you can create two lists of mums and dads and then just zip them together as point-wise crossover:

```
  do
    let n = length inputPopulation
    [mums,dads] <- replicateM 2 . replicateM n $ selectFrom inputPopulation
    return $ zipWith crossover mums dads
```

Comment: What about this solution:

```crossoverPop :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
crossoverPop pop newPop
  | length newPop < length pop = newPop ++ [crossover mum dad]
  | otherwise = newPop
  where
    mum = select pop
    dad = select pop
    select = selectFrom pop```

Comment: Not a good solution. Repeated checking of a `length` is awkward (and actually really inefficient, if you're using linked lists). There's no reason to explicitly have the partially-built `newPop` around, just build it up as the result as you go. Yes, this can also be done with recursion instead of a standard looping construct, but why bother? (Also, `select` is not going to be possible as a pure function, this must be a monadic action – preferrably in a dedicated random monad, but IO will also do.)

Comment: Or go with Carl's zipping suggestion, that's perhaps even nicer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a zip operation. Create two lists by sampling from the input n times each. Combine them with `zipWith crossover`.

The input sampling is another challenge, and honestly quite a lot trickier, especially when considering performance. But you haven't provided nearly enough details to suggest a good approach there.

Comment: There are good libraries that make sampling relatively painless. See my answer for an example of a particularly lightweight one (at least, lightweight in programmer resources; since sampling is unlikely to be the hotspot in this algorithm, this feels like a good thing to optimize for to me).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a new organism for each existing one, you should loop over the existing ones. So, with this boilerplate stubbing out the things you verbally stubbed out in your question:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Random
import Data.Traversable

data Organism

crossover :: Organism -> Organism -> Organism
crossover = undefined
```

The `Control.Monad.Random` module is provided by the [`MonadRandom` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom). Then you can write this, and it compiles fine and has the right semantics:

```
breed :: MonadRandom m => [Organism] -> m [Organism]
breed old = for old $ \_ -> liftA2 crossover (uniform old) (uniform old)
```

Nice and succinct, and I think even quite readable!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a sloppy implementation of what you asked. I don't have acces to `System.Random` module so the part of selecting random mums/dads is ommited but proposed as an untested code. As `crossover` I am using concatenation. Notice than using `!!` in list is not recommended due to performance issues when accesing linked lists by index. Try a different data structure if you wish

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

{- you should use System.Random module in order to get random indices. 
The function should look similar to this but I couldn't test it:

getRandomIndex :: RandomGen g => g -> [a] -> [Int]
getRandomIndex g l = take hi $ randomRs (0, hi) g
  where hi = length l

In the main function use getStdGen to get a g to feed getRandomIndex 
-}

dads = ["dad0","dad1", "dad2", "dad3", "dad4", "dad5"]
mums = ["mum0","mum1", "mum2", "mum3", "mum4", "mum5"]

dadIndex :: [Int]
dadIndex = [1,4,2,3,2,0] -- let's imagine that this is the result of getRandomIndex g dads 
mumIndex :: [Int]
mumIndex = [0,2,2,3,5,2] -- let's imagine that this is the result of getRandomIndex g mums 

-- crossover is simply string concatenation
crossover :: String -> String -> String
crossover a b = a <> b

newPopulation :: [String]
newPopulation = zipWith crossover randomMums randomDads
  where randomMums = map (mums !!) mumIndex --
        randomDads = map (dads !!) dadIndex

main = print newPopulation
```